Facebook Live Stream Graph API SDK with product_items option
HI im trying to create live stream RTMS url with product_items enum list.
Please give me solution how i can add the products , note the product id already created in facebook and it's facebook product id, also try to assign array of enum like ['productId1','productId2'] but still not working
here the code
        try {
            $response = $this->fbLatest->post("/" . $this->pageID . "/live_videos", [
                'access_token' => $this->accessToken,
                'status' => 'LIVE_NOW',
                'title' => 'testtsss',
                'description' => 'asdsadasdadasdadadad',
                'product_items' => 
                [
                        array(
                            'id' => "25252395334406077",
                            'retailer_id' => "25252395334406077",
                            'product_id' => "25252395334406077",
                            'position' => array(
                                'x' => 0.1,
                                'y' => 0.1
                            ),
                            'start_time_offset_ms' => 0,
                            'end_time_offset_ms' => 60000
                        ),
                ]
            ]);

            $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
            $stream_url = $graphNode->getField('stream_url');
            $streamID = $graphNode->getField('id');

            dd($graphNode , $stream_url);
        } catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            dd($e);
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        } catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            dd($e);
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

here the error:

Please help with this.

Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException {#1499 ▼ // app\Http\Controllers\CampaignController.php:289
#message: "(#3) Subject must be on whitelist"
#code: 3
#file: "

product_items[0] must be a valid ID string - and you're sending an array. Have you tried sending just the string? That is to say: 'product_items' => array('25252395334406077')?

can you please give me any sample curl example?

after sending the string as you mentioned this error occurred and no help found.

"error" => array:4 [▼
"message" => "(#3) Subject must be on whitelist"
"type" => "OAuthException"
"code" => 3
"fbtrace_id" => "AIEFr3UvaRJv-sC1dTXflzC"
]

"Subject must be on whitelist" sounds to me like the page you are trying to create a live stream on, must somehow be whitelisted by Facebook, before you can include product references in your stream. (But don't ask me where/how that is done or requested.)

@CBroe you are right , but my remaining application working properly , i can post video , image , fetch comments , reply to comment etc. and also live streaming working properly here the page: https://facebook.com/RizwansShop/  but specific when i assign products to live stream it give me an error.

#stackoverflow please help with this
